Forward voltage of LEDs from quantum mechanics perspective
I have a very elementary understanding of LEDs and semiconductors altogether, but a more solid understanding of QM, and I was wondering if there was a way to explain (preferably mathematically) forward voltage from a quantum mechanics perspective? I was thinking it perhaps has something to do with transition states, because we were taught in class that the conductive band is like an excited state and the valence band is like the ground state. My brain immediately thought of analogies to the hydrogenic atom, where we can directly find allowed electric dipole transition states using $$\langle\vec{d}\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3\vec{r}\ \psi^* \vec{d}\psi \neq0$$Is there a similar equation to calculate when a transition from the conductive band to the valence band is allowed, which will presumably shed light on how it's related to the photon wavelength emitted?
